# In python, how to test variables that may be other types?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a test that makes sure an API return is a success. If it is, it continues, if not, it doesn't. But the problem is, sometimes this result doesn't come back as the right type. Right now I'm testing it with:

```
if response['result'] == "success":
```

But if there's something wrong on the other end, I get a NoneType object back, and then the script crashes. Should I either:

```
#solution A, nested IFs checking lots of conditions
if type(response['result']) == "string": #not real code
    if response['result'] == "success:
```

Or:

```
#solution B
try: 
    if response['result'] == "success": 
        etc
except: 
    print("Something terrible happened.")
```

Or is it better to do something else entirely?

Comment: _"if there's something wrong on the other end, I get a NoneType object back"_. Please clarify. Is it `response` that is a NoneType? Or is it `response['result']`?

Comment: I'm not sure. The error I get is: `if response['result'] == "success": TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: What can your API return, in addition to strings? What form does the return value take? Does `response` become something else entirely, or just `response['result']`?

Comment: @Jono Your error indicates that `response` is `None`. So you'd check that with `if response is None: # error happened, do stuff`.

Comment: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - shows your 'response' is None. Use - if response and response['result'] == 'success' else: Error handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error handling is a perfectly good solution here. If you are *expecting* a particular type and don't get it, it's definitively an *exception*.

(You may also wish (defensively) not to assume that the `response` dict-like object will have a key named `result`. You can do that with the [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method.)

```
try:
    if response.get('result', '') == "success":
        …
except AttributeError: # Use AttributeError if you use the get method, TypeError if you use regular dict subscripting.
    # response was certainly not successful
```

Comment: I agree this is the right approach for handling incorrect types, but I am not sure `TypeError` is what you'd want to except (maybe what you'd want to raise). If there's no `.get()` you'd see an `AttributeError` from the call.

Answer (score 3):

```
if response is not None and response['result'] == 'success':
    # Success
else:
    # Failure
```

Comment: `if response is not None` is not idiomatic, since `None` is falsey, you could just do `if response and response['result'] == 'success'`. That said, the `try/except` answer is probably a better catch-all.

Comment: @adsmith Of course it's idiomatic. Using "is falsey" when you mean "is None" is overly broad and doesn't communicate your intent as well. See also: [PEP 8](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: Testing for every case of what `response` could be is the opposite of what good Python code should do. In this case, we're ONLY interested in `response` if it is a non-empty `dict` (or other dict-like-object), not whether or not it's any type OTHER than `None`. Using `if type(response)==dict and response['result'] == 'success'` would be even more specific, but you aren't advocating for that. Regardless, if you expect a dictionary and will occasionally be given a `None` instead, that is an exception and should be handled as such.

Comment: He's not testing every case. The very purpose of `None` is to provide a value indicating the lack of a value of the otherwise expected type, and as such there is nothing wrong with verifying that a value is not `None` before assuming it is, e.g., string-valued.

Comment: @adsmith: But explicit is better than implicit, and testing for None  communicates explicitly that the value is either None or a dictionary with a key 'result' in it.